# DigitalOcean App Platform deployment throwing ;Function not implemented' error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, digital-ocean

I've deployed an app onto the DigitalOcean app platform. Part of my code uses the following snippet which uses ThreadPools.

```
    try:
        with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool:
            all_data = pool.starmap(get_price_data_ticker, zip(
                tickers, start_dates, end_dates, currency))
            logger.debug('Obtained data, concatenating')
            concat_data = pd.concat(
                all_data, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker', 'Date'])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Please provide at least one ticker')
    return concat_data
```

This works fine on my dev machine but throws an errno 38 on the DigitalOcean deployment. Full tracestack below. Any ideas why? Is this a limitation of the system or do I need to add something?

I'm using the Basic version which has 512 MB RAM | 1 vCPU  x  1

Thanks!

```
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30 Traceback (most recent call last):
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 190, in handle_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     response = self.handle_exception(e)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     rv = self.dispatch_request()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return func(*args, **kwargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/app/routes.py", line 32, in index
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return update_pf()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return func(*args, **kwargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/app/routes.py", line 95, in update_pf
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     df = pf.info_date(as_at_date, hide_zero_pos=hide_zero, no_update=no_update)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/app/portfolio.py", line 114, in info_date
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     prices_df = self.curr_positions(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/app/portfolio.py", line 392, in curr_positions
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     prices_df = data.get_price_data(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/utils/data.py", line 75, in get_price_data
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool:
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 925, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 196, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     self._change_notifier = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 113, in SimpleQueue
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 336, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30     sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 13:04:30 OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19 [2020-12-16 04:31:19 +0000] [12] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19 Traceback (most recent call last):
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 190, in handle_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 625, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     response = self.handle_exception(e)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     raise value
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     rv = self.dispatch_request()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return func(*args, **kwargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/app/routes.py", line 32, in index
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return update_pf()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return func(*args, **kwargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/app/routes.py", line 95, in update_pf
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     df = pf.info_date(as_at_date, hide_zero_pos=hide_zero, no_update=no_update)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/app/portfolio.py", line 114, in info_date
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     prices_df = self.curr_positions(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/app/portfolio.py", line 392, in curr_positions
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     prices_df = data.get_price_data(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/utils/data.py", line 75, in get_price_data
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     with ThreadPool(processes=10) as pool:
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 925, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 196, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     self._change_notifier = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 113, in SimpleQueue
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 336, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 57, in __init__
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19     sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(
portfolio-tracker | 2020-12-16 15:31:19 OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after several days of dealing with digital ocean support was told:

> We discovered  that multiprocessing pools use a syscall that is not supported by App Platform. We are working on adding support for it but there is no ETA as of now.